# GMT Timezone from Zone Id

Tags: java, timezone

I need to get the GMT Time zone value in the following format: `GMT+05:30` or `MST-07:00` from the zone ID in Java.

Egs of zone IDs:

```
String zoneId ="America/Phoenix" or "Asia/Calcutta"
```

Comment: use `TimeZone#getOffset()`, then convert millis to hours to create a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in Java 8:

```
LocalDateTime curTime = LocalDateTime.now();

String zoneId ="America/Phoenix";
String gmtZoneId = "GMT" + ZoneId.of(zoneId).getRules().getOffset(curTime);
System.out.println(gmtZoneId); // GMT-07:00 will be printed
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to [java.util.TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html).

Here is a Java 7 example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String id = "America/Phoenix";
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(id);
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeZone.getRawOffset());
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeZone.getRawOffset())
            - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours);
    System.out.println("timeZone(" + id + ") = " + String.format("GMT%02d:%02d", hours, minutes));
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Ok, I included an example.

Comment: @TheThom Your are right. This doesn't give the correct example. I had the same snippet and it gives me output as GMT-7:00 but i want it as GMT-07:00

Comment: @Craig I have already tried the string formatter. It will still not work. and the output will be GMT-7:00 only

Comment: So you changed it from `GMT%d:%02d` to `GMT%02d:%02d` and that didn't work?